# Regular expression matching in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to find two similar strings with at least one error.
I want to use pythons built in re library.

example

```
import re

re.match(r"anoother","another") #this is None indeed
```

it should return True and find if it has one or two typos.

i have looked for a long re documentations 
but i have no idea how to use this knowledge when there is one type

```
a="this is the anoother line\n"
b="this is the another line\n"
c=re.search(r"{}".format(a),b) #how to write regex code here? 
#c =True  #it should return True
```

I expect return `True`

```
re.any_regex_func(r"anyregex this is anoother line anyregex","this is another line")
```

if it has more than one type return false

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool here. You might try looking at algorithms for determining edit distance.

Comment: Google something like "python fuzzy string matching", regex is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: In the standard library there is "difflib" module for such tasks.

Comment: Ok. i am new to regex that is why i asked if it is possible . i can write the algorithm without regex.

Comment: Thank you all! i will search for another libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *fuzzy matching* but unfortunately the re module doesn't provide this feature.

However the [pypi/regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module has it and is easy to use (you can set the number of character insertion, deletion, substitution and errors allowed for a group in the pattern). Example:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.match(r'(?:anoother){d}', 'another')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='another', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 1)>
```

The `{d}` allows deletions for the non-capturing group, but you can set the maximum allowed writing something like `{d<3}`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the variances of `another`. But, maybe we could add a middle capturing groups with negative lookbehind and pass your desired `another`s and fail those undesired ones. Maybe, here we could define our expression similar to:

```
^((.+?)(another?|anoother?)(.+))$
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Isaky9/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Python Demo

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "this is the other line\n"
expression = r'^((.+?)(another?|anoother?)(.+))$'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
 Sorry! No matches!
```